# Premiere Pro: Curves for adjusting video effects and its keyframes?

Tags: premiere, editing, effects

I am pretty new to Premiere, so this is probably going to be a "noob" question. So I want to make keyframed adjustments in my clips position (it just moves from one place to another) and I want to make this effect look more natural by making the movement build up speed. The clip would start moving slow then it speeds up, and finally it slows down to the end.
I saw a few random videos including Premiere, where at the place of the keyframe timeline,  there is a curve timeline window. I mean, a window where you can adjust the speed and the direction of a certain effect value by dragging the curve's point on the 2 axises.

I hope I composed this clearly and that I didn't ask something dumb :D
Thank you for the answer.

Here is a screenshot of my test project:

[image: My project]

And these are the curves I am referring to (I'm sorry for the resoltuion, but it's from a video):

[image: These cheeky little curves...]

Comment: You can adjust the keyframe interpolation in the Effect Settings panel. Might have to toggle that option or set the keyframes to an adjustable interpolation mode first. Make sure to click to little right-pointing arrow next to the title of the effect you want to adjust in the Effect Settings panel. (See the screenshots [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/why-does-adobe-premiere-cc-change-my-ease-out-keyframe-interpolation-to-bezie/20884#20884)). If you can't find the option, post a couple of screenshots of your Premiere Pro window so I can tell what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to be honest, it wasn't 100% clear to me, and I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. I edited my post with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the display of the keyframe timeline by clicking the little arrowhead to the left of each individual effect in the *Effect Controls* panel. If you can't see the panel, you can open it from the *Window* menu. If you don't see any effects in that panel, make sure to select the correct clip from your current timeline.

Here's your image with the arrowhead encircled in red (in the top left):

[image: Premiere Pro: Keyframe display toggle]

For more information on setting smooth transitions using keyframes, check out [my answer here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/why-does-adobe-premiere-cc-change-my-ease-out-keyframe-interpolation-to-bezie/20884#20884).

Comment: Worth noting that to quickly add ease to keyframes you can right-click them and choose the interpolation and ease in the drop-down menu

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll definitely check it out and I'll come with the result!